# R Join table by earliest visit

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi I have table that looks like this:

```
Customer|Cluster|Segment|Visit|Earliest Visit|
    A   |  D    |  A    | 2018|  2018        |
    A   |  D    |  B    | 2019|  2018        |
    B   |  D    |  C    | 2017|  2017        |
    B   |  D    |  D    | 2018|  2017        |
```

In R, How can I change the column Earliest Visit to only show the first visit in the column, and the rest to NA for each customer? Result should look like:

```
Customer|Cluster|Segment|Visit|Earliest Visit|
    A   |  D    |  A    | 2018|  2018        |
    A   |  D    |  B    | 2019|  NA          |
    B   |  D    |  C    | 2017|  2017        |
    B   |  D    |  D    | 2018|  NA          |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in `base` like below:

```
df[duplicated(df$Customer), 'Earliest Visit'] <- NA
```

Or with `replace`:

```
transform(df, `Earliest Visit` = replace(`Earliest Visit`, duplicated(Customer), NA))
```

The same option with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(`Earliest Visit` = replace(`Earliest Visit`, duplicated(Customer), NA))
```

Or also:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Customer) %>%
  mutate(`Earliest Visit` = replace(`Earliest Visit`, row_number() > 1, NA)) %>% ungroup
```

Output:

```
  Customer Cluster Segment Visit Earliest Visit
1        A       D       A  2018           2018
2        A       D       B  2019             NA
3        B       D       C  2017           2017
4        B       D       D  2018             NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned join, you could use the `sqldf` package here:

```
library(sqldf)
sql <- "SELECT Customer, Cluster, Segment, Visit,
            CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Visit END AS \"Earliest Visit\"
        FROM
        (
            SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY Visit) rn
            FROM your_df
        ) t"

result <- sqldf(sql)
```

Answer (score 1):

Fastest way to do this is to use the mighty **data.table** package.

```
library(data.table)

dt = data.table( Customer = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
                 Cluster = rep("D", 4),
                 Segment = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                 Visit = c( 2018, 2019, 2017, 2018),
                 Earliest_Visit = c( 2018, 2018, 2017, 2017) 
                 )
dt[ , dup := duplicated( dt, by = "Earliest_Visit" ) ]
dt[ (dup), Earliest_Visit := NA_integer_ ]
dt[ , dup := NULL ]

> dt
   Customer Cluster Segment Visit Earliest_Visit
1:        A       D       A  2018           2018
2:        A       D       B  2019             NA
3:        B       D       C  2017           2017
4:        B       D       D  2018             NA
```